# DynamoDB: getting table description null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to have a query on DynamoDB.

Currently I made so far this code:

```
AWSCredentials creds = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials();

AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds);
client.withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);   

DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds));

Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("dev");

QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec().withKeyConditionExpression("tableKey = :none.json");

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

System.out.println(table);
```

The returned value of `table` is:  `{dev: null}`, which means the that teh description is null.

It's important to say that while i'm using AWS CLI with this command: `aws dynamodb list-tables` i'm getting a result of all the tables so if i'm also making the same operation over my code `dynamoDB.listTables()` is retrieving empty list.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
Do I need to define some more credentials before using DDB API ?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem and landed here looking for a solution. As mentioned in javadoc of getDesciption

> Returns the table description; or null if the table description has
> not yet been described via {@link #describe()}.  No network call.

Initially description is set to null. After the first call to describe(), which makes a network call, description gets set and getDescription can be used after that.

Comment: [Refer documentation of the DynamoDB class](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/fb7c76a3d6180ea2e0189616f5a0ab18ae0d5649/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.java#L136)